# Generate passwords

Tags: excel, vba

I need generate passwords that do not repeat and do not have the same consecutive number, in addition to having a length of 8 digits, only numbers. All this in Visual Basic for applications Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you only want numbers, a random number between 0 and 9 can be achieved by `Int(Rnd() * 10)`.
Int() rounds down, Rnd() returns a number between 0 and <1.
If you then loop that 8 times and add the numbers after each other (with `&` rather than `+`) with an `If` checking the last last added value to the one we want to add, then you have an 8 digit number with no repeating numbers.

Then you just have to print or save them somewhere.

Something like:

```
Sub random()
Dim test As Long, ran As Long, i As Long, j As Long
For j = 1 To 500 '- Amount of numbers to print
    ran = 0
    For i = 1 To 8 '- Length of random number
        test = Int(Rnd() * 10)
        If test = Right(ran, 1) Then
            i = i - 1 '-Same number, try again
        Else
            ran = ran & test '-New number, add this
        End If
    Next i
    Range("A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row).Value = ran '- Print on last row of column "A"
Next j
Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1 '- Remove duplicates from column "A"
End Sub
```

This would then print 500 random 8 digit numbers starting from `A2`, or the last empty cell in column `A`. Then proceed with removing the duplicates.

You could check for duplicates each time, and thus making sure you actually end up with the specified amount of numbers. But it's extremely slow, and the chance to get a duplicate is really small (testrun of 10.000 numbers had a single duplicate for me).